# I have data in a column and want to move in one row with a symbol

Tags: notepad++

If I have data as

```
1234
5793
74022
749020
```

in a text file, and I want it to be like

```
1234|5793|74022|749020
```

how can I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R`
- Replace with: `|`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R      : any kind of linebreak (\r or \n or \r\n)
```

**Replacement:**

```
|       : a pipe character
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1234|5793|74022|749020
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit Ctrl+H in Search Mode Extended

Replace All

```
\r\n
```

with

```
|
```